# How can I change the color of the positive button on alertdialog?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to change the color of the positive button. How can I do this?

AlerDialog:

```
fun onSomeClicked(view: View) {
    val dialog: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(view.context)
    dialog.setTitle("SomeText")
            .setMessage("SomeMessage")
            .setPositiveButton(view.context.getString(R.string.ok_dialog)) { p0, p1 ->
                onCheckPassword(view)
            }
            .setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.cancel_dialog)) { p0, p1 ->

            }
            .create()
            .show()

}
```

Thanks!
(My question is in kotlin, with do in kotlin.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some small changes will do the thing you want-

```
val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.setTitle("SomeText")
           .setMessage("SomeMessage")
           .setPositiveButton("OK") {
               dialog, which -> dialog.dismiss()
           }
           .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which -> dialog.dismiss()

           }
           .create()
dialog.show()

dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.BLUE)

dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
```

hope it will be helpful.